# UITableView in a UIViewController, problem with datasource?

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have this:

```
@interface HomePage : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
 UITableView *myTable;
 NSMutableArray *data;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *myTaböe;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutable *data;
```

and then I have connected via IB the myTable with datasource and delegate in "File's Owner".
I am then initializing data to an empty array in the viewDidLoad method.

After I perform a HTTP call to retrieve some data, add items to the data and:

```
int i= 0;
    while(barfoo is true){
      [data insertObject:r atIndex:i];
      NSArray *insertIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i  inSection:0],nil];
      UITableView *tv = (UITableView *)self.myTable;
      [tv beginUpdates];
      [tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
      [tv endUpdates];
    i++;
    }
```

but nothing happens..... why?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess it's because you are updating the `tv` table, and your view actually displays `myTable`. I don't see the relevant part of the code, but make sure your UIView actually works with the correct table.

Also, if that brings you nowhere, trying adding a [myTable reloadData] or [tv reloadData] somewhere. But I think the problem is in the first paragraph - if that doesn't work, I don't see why this should...